# Let $A,B:V\to V$ positive definite operators in complex linear space with inner product $V$, $dimV<\infty$

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, multilinear-algebra

Let $$A,B:V\to V$$ positive definite operators in complex linear space with inner product $$V$$, $$dimV<\infty$$ Show that $$log det(A\cdot B^{-1})=-\int_{0}^\infty tr(e^{-t\cdot A}-e^{-t\cdot B}){dt\over t}$$

Can anyone help me and give me a proof?